# Write into a file using 'file = file_name' in print statement in python

Tags: python

In book headfirstpython in chapter4 they have used the syntax

```
print(list_name, file= output_file_name)
```

For them it's working fine, but for me it's giving syntax error on `file = output_file_name`. The python version is same i.e. 3.

code:
import os

man = []
other = []

try:
    data = open('sketch.txt')

```
for each_line in data:
    try:
        (role, line_spoken) = each_line.split(':', 1)
        line_spoken = line_spoken.strip()
        if role == 'Man':
            man.append(line_spoken)
        elif role == 'Other Man':
            other.append(line_spoken)
    except ValueError:
        pass

data.close()
```

except IOError:
    print('The datafile is missing!')

try:
    man_file = open('man_data.txt', 'w')
    other_file = open('other_data.txt', 'w')

```
print(man, file=man_file)
print(other, file=other_file)
```

except IOError:
    print('File error.')

finally:
    man_file.close()
    other_file.close()

Comment: Please post a more complete example, for those of us who want to help but don't have the book you're reading.

Answer (score 1):

As per the help of print function indicates

> file:  a file-like object (stream); defaults to the current
>   sys.stdout.

So the input is not supposed to be file-name but rather a file-like object. If you want to write into (say) a text file, you need to first open it for writing and use the file handle.

```
f = open("output.txt",'w')
print(list_name, file=f)
```

Comment: @phd by 'input' I meant input argument of print function.